# Connect two extra monitors to laptop

Tags: graphics, video-card, hardware-port

I have following models of graphics card in my DELL Inspiron 5520 15R:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
```

Laptop has one HDMI port and one VGA port. When I try to connect two external monitors on each of these ports, I can only use one at a time.

Is there anyway to use two external screens at the same time given the configurations I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation with laptops that by default you can only use one extra display at a time, reason being the graphic adapter. So to run more than 2 displays you will need a little extra hardware. You can have a look at this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gn9VZq-nDj8) video.